# Use server side variable in jquery MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having a server side global variable in my MVC4 application.

And now i need to use that variable in my View using j Query.

Can any one tell me how can i use that variable in my View using j Query.

### Variable

```
namespace Saif.Models
{
    public class ClsGlobal
    {
        static string _AbsoluterUrl;
        public static string AbsoluterUrl
        {
            get { return _AbsoluterUrl; }
            set { _AbsoluterUrl = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

### In J query $(document).ready

```
var url = @Saif.Models.ClsGlobal.AbsoluterUrl;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `''` to the url in your javascript:

```
var url = '@Saif.Models.ClsGlobal.AbsoluterUrl';
```

The `url` will now contain the value of `AbsoluteUrl`.

Answer (score 0):

save server side  variable value to hidden fields and then use hidden field value in jquery  with the help of hidden fields id.